# java - onMousePressed() only detecting once

Tags: java, swing

I have an array of JLabels[7] and I filled all JLabels with same image and added them to a JPanel.

When I click on a JLabel position(e.g I click on JLabel[5]) the console will print out "you have clicked JLabel 5" and change the JLabel image from imageOne to imageTwo.

I realized something about my codes which is after I clicked on a JLabel (e.g I click on JLabel[5]), the image changes from imageOne to imageTwo and the console print out "you have clicked JLabel 5" but if I clicked again and again on JLabel[5], the program will not detect my mouse click event and the console will not print out "you have clicked JLabel 5".

How do I make it such a way that after image has changed on the first click on a JLabel, it will still contiune and detect no mater how many times I clicked on the same JLabel again?.

```
 import java.awt.FlowLayout;
 import java.awt.Image;
 import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
 import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
 import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
 import java.io.File;
 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;

 public class LearningSwing {

     public Image imageOne() {
         BufferedImage img = null;
         try {
             img = ImageIO.read(new File("imageOne.jpg"));   
         } catch (Exception e) {
           }
         return img;
    }

    public Image imageTwo() {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("imageTwo.jpg"));    
        } catch (Exception e) {
          }
        return img;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JLabel[] jLabelArr = new JLabel[7];
        final JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final LearningSwing learningSwing = new LearningSwing();
        for(int i = 0; i< 7; i++) {
            jLabelArr[i] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(learningSwing.imageOne()));
            jPanel.add(jLabelArr[i]);
            jLabelArr[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i ++) {
                        if(e.getSource() == jLabelArr[i]) { 
                            System.out.println("You clicked on JLabel" + i);
                            jPanel.remove(i);
                            jLabelArr[i] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(learningSwing.imageTwo()));
                            jPanel.add(jLabelArr[i],i);
                            jPanel.revalidate();
                            jPanel.repaint();   
                        }
                    }
                }
            });     
        }
        frame.add(jPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(400,600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are removing the old `JLabel` when the listener invokes `mouseClicked`, and you are recreating it again with the new image. This causes the `JLabel` to lose the listener.

You could instead change the image of the label as follows:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (e.getSource() == jLabelArr[i]) {
            System.out.println("You clicked on JLabel" + i);
            jLabelArr[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(learningSwing.imageTwo()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is right, but likely no need to revalidate and repaint after swapping icons. 1+

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to re-add any listeners. You need to not swap JLabels. Instead, keep your JLabels where they are and just swap ImageIcons. The key here is this: don't make things more difficult for yourself.

---

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LearningSwing2 extends JPanel {
   private static final String[] IMAGE_PATHS = {"imageOne.jpg", "imageTwo.jpg"};
   private static final int LABEL_COUNT = 7;
   private List<Icon> icons = new ArrayList<>();
   private JLabel[] imageLabels = new JLabel[LABEL_COUNT];


   public LearningSwing2() throws IOException {
      for (String imagePath : IMAGE_PATHS) {
         BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
         icons.add(new ImageIcon(img));
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < imageLabels.length; i++) {
         imageLabels[i] = new JLabel(icons.get(0));
         imageLabels[i].addMouseListener(new LabelListener());
      }
   }

   private class LabelListener extends MouseAdapter {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mEvt) {
         JLabel label = (JLabel) mEvt.getSource();
         for (int i = 0; i < imageLabels.length; i++) {
            if (label == imageLabels[i]) {
               System.out.println("You pressed image label " + i);
            }
         }
         label.setIcon(icons.get(1));
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      LearningSwing2 mainPanel;
      try {
         mainPanel = new LearningSwing2();
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("LearningSwing2");
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
         frame.setVisible(true);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```